# if statement of objective in linear programming

Tags: python, linear-programming, pyomo

I am trying to code a Linear Programming model with Pyomo. I have a question about the if statement. Let objective is minimum the time of all jobs done.

```
          Job1  Job2  Setup  
machine1  25    30    30  
machine2  40    50    50  
machine3  35    59    60
```

Each machine needs to be set up at least once, **if machine 1 and machine 2 both are being used, we need extra 20 mins.**

I have read some posts about the big-M method that can solve this problem. But I don't know how to do it when it related to the objective. Thanks!

Comment: We can't see the problem if you don't provide any code!

Answer (score 1):

Let `m(i)∈{0,1}` indicating if machine i is used. Then the additional setup time  can look like:

```
  both12Time ≥ 20*(m(1) + m(2) - 1)
  both12Time ≥ 0
```

We assume here total time is minimized.